# Install windows on chroot of linux

Tags: linux, windows, chroot

How do I install Windows on chroot in Linux, if it is possible at all. I am confused about the meaning of chroot so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chroot` command (or system call) changes the root directory for a specific process (or set of processes). So a process started as `/home/user/bin/program` could be chroot'ed to `/home/user/`. To the process `/home/user` would appear as `/` (the root directory), so it would be unable to access any files from directories above `/home/user` (and thus (arguably) making the system more secure).

Next, what you are asking is impossible. Chroot is a Linux kernel feature. It will not allow you to do any virtualization, or even running a different operating system. If you want to run Windows on your Linux box, I'd suggest you look into [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or  [Linux KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page).